# sql query to retrieve numeric and alphanumeric entries

Tags: sql

Hi can anyone help with a quire to retrieve both numeric and alpha numeric entries from a column.

Example: Column is 'ID' and entries could be = abc0000 or could be all 9999999999.

The search is a list of numeric and alphanumeric items.

Example: 8765398
         ha34789
         ss0487667
         7629

Comment: Column data type? In SQL a column has a specified datatype. If you store numbers in a character column, those numbers are stored as character data.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'`

You could also use a *named character*:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$'`

Comment: Hi IIia Rostovtsev sorry i am quiet new to this. So in your example where do i add my search list

Comment: @DavidJohns What do you mean? You add it `SQL` query! (this is the query itself actually)

Comment: Ameya Deshpande Sorry it is a MSSQL database.

Comment: Ilia Rostovtsev will your first line gives this error 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.'

Comment: As far as I know, MS SQL Server (2008) does not support regular expressions directly. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server

Comment: Ilia Rostovtsev so what you are saying is there is no quick quiry I can use to search for a list of numeric and alphanumeric entries

Comment: @DavidJohns David, in case I'm correct and MS SQL doesn't support `regexp` than you should build a function (read a post from the link above) or use `%`. I can't say for sure as I don't use MS SQL and you never mentioned it at the first place!